# How to use JDBC (MYSQL) in Akka-http using Scala language?

Tags: mysql, scala, jdbc, akka-http

I have to use JDBC(MySQL database) using Scala language in Akka-http. I know the connection part instead I want to know how to use plain SQL queries in JDBC and how database and table are getting created.

Comment: Maybe slick can be a good solution: https://doc.akka.io/docs/alpakka/current/slick.html#plain-sql-queries

Comment: @EmilianoMartinez do you have any GitHub project for plain SQL queries using Scala language in akk